# Entity framework setting ID when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following entity model:

[image: Entity Model]

I add a bunch of tasks and start processing these tasks. After each task completion, I want to log information about it.

I do so with the following code:

```
TASK scheduledTask = entities.TASKs.First(x => x.TASK_NAME == e.ClassName);
scheduledTask.NEXT_RUN = e.NextRun;
entities.SaveChanges();

TASK_LOG logMsg = new TASK_LOG()
{
    TASK = scheduledTask,
    MESSAGE = e.TaskResult.Message,
    STATUS = e.TaskResult.Status ? "Successful" : "Failure",
    TIMESTAMP = e.CompletedTime
};
entities.TASK_LOG.AddObject(logMsg);
entities.SaveChanges();
```

However, I am getting an exception stating that I cannot modify the ID property of the TASK_LOG object. I don't see how my code would be modifying the `logMsg` object ID property.

Note: The ID property in both entities are generated by the database and are set to `StoreGeneratedPattern` - Identity.

**Edit:**

2nd Run - Now I am getting an error about having a connection open/avaliable on the first `SaveChanges` call.

3rd Run - Getting a error Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). On the last `SaveChanges` call.

This error inconsistency is making it hard to fix.

Comment: How is AddObject unneeded? I create a TASK_LOG object but it isn't attached to anything related to the database until I add it to the entities. 

See my edited post about the error.

Comment: I'm thinking you need to do : entities.TASK.AddObject(scheduledTask); before the frist .SaveChanges; then remove entities.TASK_LOG.AddObject(logMsg);

Comment: @MikeTWebb no, the `TASK scheduledTask` is already attached and does not need to be re-added.

Comment: @CodeCaster....Gotcha....agreed on then TASK_LOG.AddObject() not being necessayr.  Would Justin need to do entities.Entry(scheduledTask).State = EntityState.Modified before doing the second SaveChanges()?

Comment: EF modifies the `ID` property of course when it accepts the changes the database has done (namely autogenerated the `ID` value), but that should not be a problem. "*an exception stating that I cannot modify the ID property"*: Can you show the *exact* exception message, exception type and possible inner exception. Also: At which line of code does the exception occur?

Comment: @Slauma Sure. It will tomorrow as I am home from work today. Tired of beat my head on it anyway.

Comment: What database/provider are you using for this?

Comment: @dustmouse. I have already resolved this issue.

Comment: Okay, I didn't see where it had been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem may be because you are setting the logMsg.TASK property before it has been attached to the context via AddObject. Since you have access to the foreign key, I suggest creating the reference using the TASK_ID property instead of the TASK navigation property. Please try substituting this code for your logMsg:

```
TASK_LOG logMsg = new TASK_LOG()
{
    TASK_ID = scheduledTask.ID,
    MESSAGE = e.TaskResult.Message,
    STATUS = e.TaskResult.Status ? "Successful" : "Failure",
    TIMESTAMP = e.CompletedTime
};
```

Comment: I do a save changes after I create the TASK to add it to the context beforehand in code not shown. As for your example code, I tried doing that as well to no avail.